# Logging errors and warnings in the browser console with vanilla JavaScript

Tags: javascript, logging, console.log

Is there a way to log WARN and ERROR messages to the console using Vanilla JavaScript?

An example would be something that looks like:

[image]

I could just print it with `console.log()` but it prints without color as just a plain message. I'd like to print it as an error or warning so it's colored output and background.

Most online guides suggest using some logger library such as log4javascript. I'm hoping to do this without pulling in any dependency.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You can use `console.warn` and `console.error` functions. First for warnings and second for errors.

https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Console/error
https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Console/warn

Answer (score 1):

`console.warn('warning message');`

> Outputs a warning message to the Web Console.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console/warn

`console.error('error message');`

> Outputs an error message to the Web Console.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console/error